# Laravel perform scheduled job on database

Tags: database, laravel, scheduled-tasks, pipeline

This is somewhat a design question for my current laravel side project.

So currently I have a table that stores a status value in one column and the date when that status should be altered. No I want to alter that status value automatically when the date is stored is the current date. Since that table will gain more rows about time I have to perform that altering process in a repeating manner. As well as that I want to perform some constraint checks on the data as well.

Im sure laravel is capable of doing that, but how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Laravel` has commands and a scheduler, combining these two gives exactly what you want.

Create your command in `Console\Commands` folder, with your desired logic. Your question is sparse, so most of it is pseudo logic and you can adjust it for your case.

```
namespace App\Console\Commands;

class StatusUpdater extends Command
{

    protected $signature = 'update:status';

    protected $description = 'Update status on your model';

    public function handle()
    {
        $models = YourModel::whereDate('date', now())->get();

        $models->each(function (YourModel $model) {
            if ($model->status === 'wrong') {
                $model->status = 'new';
                $model->save();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

For this command to run daily, you can use the scheduler to schedule the given command. Go to `Commands\Kernel.php` where you will find a schedule() method.

```
use App\Commands\StatusUpdater;
use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;

    class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
    {
        protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
        {
            $schedule->command(StatusUpdater::class)->daily();
        }
    }
}
```

For scheduling to work, you have to add the following command to `cronjob` on your server. Which is described in the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling#running-the-scheduler).

```
* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```